# persist dialog by navigation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

what I have is a music application, which I want to handle a dialog of music buttons with a stream, means I want to persist this dialog by navigations but as you know if we push to another page, we will miss the dialog for the new route.

is it possible to have such this dialog in flutter which we could handle it above all routes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never tried this, give it a go,

```
MaterialApp(
    home: Stack(
      children: [
        Navigator(
          //consider this as your router
          //push-pop etc
          initialRoute: "/",
          onGenerateRoute: (settings){
            if(settings.name=="/"){
              return MyMusicPlayerHome();
            } else {
              
            }
          },
        ),
        MyMusicPlayerDialog()
      ],
    ),
  )
```